# Karate WebSocket API Testing

Tags: karate

For my API i need to test websocket. The websocket listens from one channel and sends to another channel(/user/fromserver , /user/toserver). Also need to send authorization token when creating connection and when connection is closed. How can i do that in karate?

I have already referred this https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/websocket but not sure this is what i need.

i have also checked this https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/775. The karate version i have is 0.9.5

But i am getting this error.

javascript evaluation failed: karate.webSocket(demoUrl,null, null, headers), TypeError: Can not invoke method [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.OverloadedDynamicMethod
WebSocketClient com.intuit.karate.core.ScriptBridge.webSocket(String,Function,Map)
WebSocketClient com.intuit.karate.core.ScriptBridge.webSocket(String,Function)
WebSocketClient com.intuit.karate.core.ScriptBridge.webSocket(String)
] with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in  at line number 1.

Comment: yes that is what you need. please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#websocket - and if you are still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas. Thanks for your response. i have edited the question. Please take a look .

Comment: sorry, works for me. I have nothing to add to my comment above